# Project part of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

If I understand correctly, Micosoft Project 2013 is today a part of SharePoint 2013 enterprise. Is it true?

Comment: No, but it is built on SharePoint 2013: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/projectserver/fp123552.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, but it is built on SharePoint 2013:

[Capabilities and features in Project Server 2013 and Project Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/projectserver/fp123552.aspx)

Comment: This was a bit of a funny answer! ;)